# d3 updating 'width' attribute of bar is not working when values range change

Tags: d3.js

PLEASE Help! New with d3js. Drawing a pyramid graph based on https://www.jasondavies.com/d3-pyramid/

Bars are not updated properly when change data e.i. the data range is different from the range the graph was first created - data range go beyond the domain range in which it was defined. The pyramid graph will change when the user choose a value to filter the data. The graph is not drawn correctly once the data is filtered (subtotal counts) - and try to redraw the graph. If I select total counts again (default graph), it is drawn correctly.

- First pyramid graph has data range [0,99999] of total counts. It is created perfectly.
- Filter data to get subtotal counts and the ranges is smaller [0, 999]. The range of values has change

It seems the update is not working properly and uses the old values to do the current calculation for the 'x' value. Please see pics below to see the effect

Update attributes of the 'rect' elements code

```
bars.selectAll("rect.femalebar")
.transition()
.attr("x", function(d) { return (innerMargin - total(d.f) - 2 * labelSpace); }) 
.attr("width", function(d) { return total(d.f); });
```

`total = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, dataRange]).range([0, chartWidth - labelSpace])`

Full code can be seen at https://github.com/aniuska/DataScience/blob/master/Viz-D3/d3pyramid_viz.js

Original Graph

[image]

Graph after filtering data

[image]